# Look strange on gvim after applying Source Sans Pro font

Tags: linux, fonts, gvim

I downloaded the `Source Sans Pro` font and install on my Fedora17(Xfce). I did `mkfontscale`, `mkfontdir`, `fc-cache -fv`, and after `fc-list`, could see it on the list.

Then I changed `guifont` in gvim to `Source\ Sans\ Pro\ 10`, but it looks quite strange. And then I changed it to `DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ 10`, it looks nothing strange.

So, why would this happend? And how to solve it? Thanks!

[image: Source\ Sans\ Pro\ 10]
**Source Sans Pro**

[image: DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ 10]
**DejaVu Sans Mono**

Comment: which is which?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek First is `Source Sans Pro`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe gvim has a problem with non-monospaced fonts, rendering each character on some kind of grid, thus making it a bit like monospaced. Usually it looks pretty bad, as in this case.

My best advice is to use a  true monospaced font. I think Adobe makes a great one, similar to Source Sans Pro, it's called Source Code Pro, check this out:
http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html

Comment: DevaVu Sans Mono is, of course, monospaced. That's why it look good.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to use `Source Code Pro` but mistook the name with `Source Sans Pro`

Comment: This happens with Source Code Pro as well. It must be looking for Mono, Courier, Typewriter in the name